# jQuery .animate background-position not working in Firefox on Mac

Tags: jquery, firefox, safari, cross-browser

We've setup a cute little moving clouds animation here: http://thechildrensguide.harmonyapp.com/?password=test

It works nicely in Safari on Mac but doesn't seem to work on Firefox.

Any suggestions on what we've done wrong?

Also, does this technique use a lot of resources? Safari's CPU usage jumps from around 4% to 13% when this page is loaded. Is this script the cause?

I'd also appreciate any feedback on how it's functioning in IE (any version).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in Chrome either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error on this line.  Note you ended the statement with a , and it should be a ;

```
 function scrollBar(){
   $('#header_wrap').css("background-position","0px 0px").animate({backgroundPosition:"+500px 0px"},40000,"linear",scrollBar),
}
```